# Why can Netezza admin see a table saved to Netezza via Coginiti Pro

Tags: sql, netezza

I created a table from an excel file in Coginiti Pro and then saved it to the Netezza. I can see the table and can query from it in Coginiti Pro, Excel, and Power BI Desktop. However, the Netezza admins can not see it. It says the table does not exist, but it definitely does. Any ideas what is going on there?

The admins have tried accessing the able and it says it does not exist. I have tried granting access and I am unable to do so due to my permission level.

Answer (score 0):

Have you saved/created that table in your own schema?
Can admin try to access using DBNAME.SCHEMANAME.TABLENAME format and check?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I cannot find something through one tool that I CAN see through another tool, I have later realized that one of these things happened:

1. you look in different places (are one of you perhaps on the PROD system - the other not? … the other answer in this thread implies a similar problem)
2. you spell it wrong (are you perhaps using mixed-case names ? Netezza is Linux/postgres based, your Microsoft toolset are different in nature)

A third option is that your table is created as a TEMP table somehow, and then it’s only accessible through YOUR single connections to the database (and will be lost when you disconnect)